# Change Powerpoint presentation slide size programmatically

Tags: c#, powerpoint

When uploading a powerpoint presentation to my servers, I want to change all the slides' width and height in my presentation. I tried using openxml but to no avail.
Anyone knows how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The code I was trying to execute is this:

```
Using (var ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(path, true)
{
  ppt.PresentationPart.Presentation.SlideSize.Cy = 10;
  ppt.PresentationPart.Presentation.SlideSize.Cx = 10;
  ppt.PresentationPart.Presentation.Save();
}
```

After opening the presentation in desktop, it askes if I want to repair the presentation.

Comment: You want to change the size of the slide?? Not of some component inside each slide? How don't even know how to do it in PowerPoint..... :)

Comment: Change the size of the slide yeah. In powerpoint you can change the size from the slide size button inside the design tab

Comment: I can't find anything... what office version are you using?

Comment: Office 2013 I think

Comment: Typical cx/cy values for a 4:3 slide are <p:sldSz cx="9144000" cy="6858000"  .... Have you looked within the xml of a PPTX slide to see what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: How do you parse the presentation to xml? Plus I wrote 10 just to see if it really does the sizing

Comment: @AmitToren Beats me. You started by saying you were using openxml, so I assumed (incorrectly) that you had that part covered.  You might instead want to automate PowerPoint and modify ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight and .SlideWidth.  Caution: changing a slide's size can cause the shapes on the slide or their relationship to one another to distort.